# Override default media queries in WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a site and the client wants to have the mobile menu kick in at ~1300px vs default 768px.

All I really have to work with is a custom CSS field inside of the theme. Currently the site is pulling existing CSS in question from this `file:/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_9e42ecb6dfd481fe6fed38efb1dbf60d.css`

The specific code causing the issue is as follows:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px)
.csstransforms3d.csstransitions #navigation {
```

and

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.csstransforms3d.csstransitions #navigation {
```

Sure I could go FTP in and edit that but then I'm assuming when the client updates the theme or WP it will be overwritten.

Any solution to this? Either a) overwrite the media queries using the custom css form or b) call a different CSS file instead of `autoptimize_9e42ecb6dfd481fe6fed38efb1dbf60d.css` so I can go edit it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Updating wordpress wont affect your customization, upgrading theme will. Only solution is editing css file (make copy of old file)

Comment: Don't edit a theme's CSS, make a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can copy the css from 767 block to 1300 block. (brute force soln though :P )

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the autoptimized file (as that is an automatic aggregation of all your site's CSS from theme and plugins so your change would eventually get overwritten), but change the original CSS (likely a file that is part of your theme) or better still [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and do your corrections in there.

frank (autoptimize developer)